# php singleton object not created

Tags: php, oop, singleton

I'm trying to learn about OOP, and create a singleton to return a settings object within a PHP script. For some reason, the instance never seems to get set.

I'm echoing a message `getting settings` anytime the singleton goes through its construct (it's silent if it just returns the existing instance).

When this is called from within a script, I'm getting dozens of these `getting settings` messages, one for each time I call `mySettings::getSettings()`-- `$instance` doesn't seem to be created, even when I try to dump it immediately after it is created.

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Here's the code:

```
class mySettings {
    private $settings;
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct(){
        $configfile = "myconfig.ini";
        if(!$this->settings = parse_ini_file( $configfile )){
            die('CONFIG NOT FOUND/PARSED');
        }
    }

    public static function getSettings(){
        if ( !self::$instance ){
            echo "getting settings-- no instance found!";
            self::$instance = new mySettings();
            var_dump(self::$instance); // <-- dumps nothing
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function setParam( $key, $value ){
        $this->settings[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function getParam( $key ){
        return $this->settings[$key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Tested your code. Works.

Comment: @julio, webbiedave and i both got it to work right. perhaps something elsewhere (outside of that class) is going wrong.

Comment: thanks for the help guys. I'll update with the other functions that could be the issue and take a look at those.

Comment: Code works completely. I think the error is somewhere else. Could you show your real code?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach to creating a singleton looks correct.

Try with an empty constructor, there might be an issue with that die() statement there.

Comment: if it were dying, it would say the die message, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Kristian-- yes, in fact the die statement is operational, if I give a bad path or an empty value for the config file, it will die. Also, if I dump the value returned by `$var = mySettings::getSettings()` elsewhere, it does have the expected value.

Answer (score 0):

Does: `// <-- dumps nothing` mean you see a "NULL" being rendered or nothing at all?

Maybe you've got some output buffering that hides the var_dump() output.